# Getting values in pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the pivot table and I hope to get value in red and green rectangle

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample dataframes

df_user = pd.DataFrame( {'user': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a1', 3: 'a2', 4: 'a2', 5: 'a2', 6: 'a3', 7: 'a3', 8: 'a6', 9: 'a7', 10: 'a8'}, 'query': {0: 'orange', 1: 'strawberry', 2: 'pear', 3: 'orange', 4: 'strawberry', 5: 'lemon', 6: 'orange', 7: 'banana', 8: 'meat', 9: 'beer', 10: 'juice'}} )
df_user['count']=1
df_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df_user,index=['query'],columns=['user'],values=['count'],aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)

#getting value in red rectangle, incorrect
print(df_pivot.loc['banana':'beer','a1':'a2'])
#getting value in green rectangle, error
print(df_pivot.loc[:,'a8'])
```

What's the right way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
>> df_pivot.loc[["banana","beer"], ('count',['a1','a2'])]

        count
user    a1  a2
query       
banana  0.0 0.0
beer    0.0 0.0
```

and

```
>> df_pivot.loc[:, ('count',['a8'])]

           count
user        a8
query   
banana      0.0
beer        0.0
juice       1.0
lemon       0.0
meat        0.0
orange      0.0
pear        0.0
strawberry  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to first drop the first column level, like so:

```
df_pivot = df_pivot.droplevel(0,1)
```